# Bouncing with left to right moving and vice versa for an image using cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

how can i create an image with Bouncing ,left to right moving and vice versa  using cocos2d

Comment: box2d will be the choice

Comment: I am a beginner in box2d..can u please suggest nice tutorial for box2d.

Comment: the tutorial they provide is the best i can see. and it should works fine. try to follow it step by step and touch the ball to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Physics Engine and do create the effect. For simple tutorial Please visit the [Ray Wenderlich tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls). The tutorial has got the Box2D physics template.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer.I downloaded the sample code and run it.Bt i can't see any bouncing

Answer (score 0):

You can use below link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls